# Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please pardon my confusion as I stumble through this, I am new to javascript and this kind of thing. Please also pardon me if my code is garbage, because it is a combination of examples I found, and things I figured out (and didn't figure out)!

I am trying to run this html file in Open Broadcaster Software:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet_twitter1.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jstween-1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/countries.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var timestampOld;
            var timestamp;
            var mText4;

            var xmlDoc;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var animating = false;
            var doUpdate = false;

            function init() {

                xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

                var timeout = this.window.setInterval(function() {
                    pollHandler();
                }, 250);

                $('#mText4').html('');
                $('#board').tween({
                   top:{
                      start: '80',
                      stop: '0',
                      units: 'px',
                      time: 0,
                      duration: 0.8,
                      effect:'easeOut'
                   }
                });

                $.play();
            }



    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function pollHandler()
            {
              loadData();
              if (timestamp != timestampOld) {
                  doUpdate = true;
              }
              if (!animating && doUpdate) {
                  updateBoard();
              }
            }

            function loadData() {
                xhr.open('GET', 'streamcontrol.xml');
                xhr.send();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;


                        mText4 = getValueFromTag(xmlDoc,'mText4');                      
                        timestampOld = timestamp;
                        timestamp = getValueFromTag(xmlDoc,'timestamp');

                }
            }

            function updateBoard() {


                if ($('#mText4').html() != mText4) {
                    animating = true;
                    $('#mText4').tween({
                        opacity: {
                          start: 100,
                          stop: 0,
                          time: 0,
                          duration: 0.5,
                          effect: 'easeIn'
                        },
                        onStop: function(){
                            $('#mText4').html(mText4);
                        }
                    });

                    $('#mText4').tween({
                        opacity: {
                          start: 0,
                          stop: 100,
                          time: 0.5,
                          duration: 0.5,
                          effect: 'easeOut'
                        },
                        onStop: function(){
                            animating = false;
                        }
                    });
                }

                $.play();

                doUpdate = false;
            }

            function getValueFromTag (xmlDoc,tag) {
                if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tag).length != 0 ) {
                    if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].childNodes.length == 0) {
                            return '';
                        } else {
                            return xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
            </script>
    <div id="board">
        <div id="mText4"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works just fine, but after a few hours of having this (and two other html files) going, the software would crash. This caused me to look at the log files that it creates, and I was seeing the following a LOT of times:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null @http://absolute/D:/obs%20stuff/browserfiles/Twitter1.html334
```

So I ran it in Firefox, and it was then throwing the following error (again, a LOT):

```
TypeError: xmlDoc is null
```

I know for sure that `streamcontrol.xml` is not null. I feel like those errors are pointing me in a good direction, but after about a collective 10+ hours over two days of trying different things I have seen on different threads, I am at a loss.

Comment: `onreadystatechange` goes through many stages. make sure you check at the right point.

Comment: Did you tested it with [tag:MSIE]

Comment: I had tested with IE and everything was a disaster. Missing all kinds of permissions, it was a mess. I tried with Chrome as well, and it didn't have full permissions to access the xml document.

Comment: @DanielA.White That is what I had to do. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onreadystatechange does not only fire when your request has completed successfully. You must check that the ready state is complete and the status is successful in the handler.

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for some usage details.

Typically, you'll want to check that `xhr.readystate === 4` to know it has a response then check the status (`xhr.status === 200` means a successful response)

Comment: Adding the check for `xhr.readystate === 4` followed by a check for `xhr.status === 200` worked! I had tried something similar, but before I put them both in the same check, that they both had to be true, and (again, I don't know much about this so I could be wrong) I think it was just never making it through that validation. Thanks man, much appreciated!!! Cleared up my console errors as well as my OBS log errors!